# Why is the font size in google-chrome smaller than firefox on the same system?

Tags: firefox, fonts, google-chrome

Why is the font size in google-chrome smaller than the font size in firefox when displaying exactly the same web page (for example, wikipedia) in the same Ubuntu 11.04 system?
How can I make both use the same fonts as the ones in Firefox?

Answer (score 6):

Each browser can fix the default font size.

In Firefox you will find these settings in **Preferences -> Preferences -> content -> Fonts & Colors**

In chrome ([pulled from their website](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96810)) :

1. Click the wrench icon tools menu on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Options (Preferences on Mac and Linux).
3. Click Under the Hood.
4. In the "Web Content" section, use the "Font size" menu to make adjustments.